# ASP.NET Forms and Windows Authentication for Different Domains

Tags: asp.net, .net, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I have the following requirement: if a user in domain 2 goes into an ASP.NET site that is in domain 1, then the site should display a customised login form to validate the user. But if a user from domain 1 surfs to same the ASP.NET site (on domain 1), then Windows authentication (using Active Directory) takes place, so the user should goes straight through to the site content without seeing the login form.

How would I go about doing that?

Would I first need to detect the [request domains](http://blog.miniasp.com/post/2008/02/10/How-Do-I-Get-Paths-and-URL-fragments-from-the-HttpRequest-object.aspx)? I have tried HttpContext.Current.Request in Page_Load() but have not yet been successful in detecting which domain a request is from.

Also, how should I setup the site authentication mode? Would I need Windows authentication for domain 1 users, and [forms authentication](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240) for domain 2 users? I have also not been able to succeed in this, since IIS 7.5 complains that I cannot have both Windows and Forms authentication turned on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Surely not an answer but due to the length, I am adding it as answer not comment.
AFAIK, IIS 7.5 allows both authentications to be enabled but no through web.config, you have to do it through IIS Management console, furthermore the scenario you described is handled through claims authentication (windows for intranet and forms for extranet) in Sharepoint 2010. I think same approach can be used in ASP.NET application since Sharepoint is also built on top of ASP.NET 3.5. More over you can look into Federated Authentication APIs present in .Net. You can explore the following links [Claims Aware ASP.NET Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh291068%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Federated Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff872350.aspx) and [Enabling Federated Authentication for ASp.NET in Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/identitytrainingcourse_wifonwazlab2010_topic2.aspx). Hope this helps.